# Spring Boot: How can I ignore class Mapping in Method Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I ignore my in the class defined requestMapping in only one of my Methods?
Code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api/user/"})
@Controller
public class UserResource {

    @GetMapping("{userId}")
    public User user(
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        // Do stuff;
    }


    @GetMapping("/api/v2/user/{userId}") // <- Here I want to use the given path and ignore the class path
    public UserData userV2(
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
        // Do stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Move it to a differnt class.

Comment: Or do `@RequestMapping({"/api/"})` on the class and `@GetMapping("user/{userId}")` and `@GetMapping("v2/user/{userId}")` on your two methods.

Comment: solutions are already mentioned before. but it would be a good practice to create a complete new class for your v2 version of your endpoint